# Flex 4 Changing style options with states

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm interested in finding out the best approach to this issue, it's not technically difficult but there must be an elegant solution.

Basically i have a form that features mostly text inputs, i would like to change the style of the input boxes based on the current state.

I can do this in the mxml on each input...

```
<s:TextInput text="label" borderColor.State1="0xFFFFFF" borderColor.State2="0x000000"/>
```

But that involves creating properties on every single item in the form.

There must be a better way of doing this without adding a property to each item?

Thanks!

Comment: You can loop the children of the form and apply the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transitions and SetAction to set styles on multiple objects at the same time based on a new viewstate.  This is a piece of an example from the SDK documentation:
.

```
<s:states>
        <s:State name="Login" />
        <s:State name="Register" />
    </s:states>

    <s:transitions>
        <!-- Define the transition from the base state to the Register state.-->
        <s:Transition id="toRegister" fromState="*" toState="Register">
            <s:Sequence targets="{[loginPanel, registerLink, confirm, loginLink]}">
                <s:RemoveAction />
                <s:Fade />
                <s:SetAction target="{loginPanel}" property="title" />
                <s:SetAction target="{loginButton}" property="label" />
                <s:SetAction target="{loginButton}" property="color" />
                <s:Resize target="{loginPanel}"/>
                <s:AddAction />
                <s:Fade />
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>

        <!-- Define the transition from the Register state to the base state.-->
        <s:Transition id="toDefault" fromState="Register" toState="*">
            <s:Sequence targets="{[loginPanel, registerLink, 
                    confirm, loginLink]}">
                <s:RemoveAction/>
                <s:SetAction target="{loginPanel}" property="title"/>
                <s:SetAction  target="{loginButton}" property="label"/>
                <s:SetAction target="{loginButton}" property="color"/>
                <s:Resize target="{loginPanel}"/>
                <s:AddAction/>
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>
```

You can just target everything in the sequence (instead using different targets for each SetAction) and use the 'value' property of the SetAction to set the values to what you want.

Comment: Perfect thanks, i already have a transition between the two states so that's a nice easy solution.